# Can I reduce the usable area for an MDI client window?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I'm working on converting an application from WINAPI C to C#. I'm trying to duplicate the functionality as much as possible. Part of the application uses a set of search windows which sit inside a parent window with it being an MDI client for them. The problem is, part of the parent window may or may not display a footnote area containing some dialog regarding the search (it depends on what kind of search is being done). In the original application that area was reserved - the search windows couldn't be dragged over top of it, probably because it's technically part of the menu. I can't seem to duplicate that behaviour though.

I tried getting the MdiClient for the window and adjusting the location and size. I can change the size, but when I try to change the location value it just ignores my changes. I can't seem to find any equivalent to the footnotes in C# - Google just returns pages indicating how to do it for MS Word documents.

My plan B is to use a tab control instead.

I can't provide actual screenshots of the existing setup, but here is a mockup of what I mean, the green arrows indicate the bounds of where the MDI child windows can actually be displayed:

[image: MDI example]

Comment: Could a splitter window help? I find a weird mosaic of splitters often helps in WinForms apps

Comment: This is probably a question where pictures/screenshots would help tremendously in giving you a more specific answer or recommendation. I used to work with docking windows every day, but hard for me to picture your scenario.

Comment: Just dock a panel to the bottom (assuming bottom since you describe it as footnotes).

Comment: @LarsTech That won't help. A panel cannot be an MDI client container, only a form can.

Comment: I didn't say the panel was a client container.  If you dock a panel to the top of the mdi parent, it will reduce the size of the mdi client space.